# Cannot get factory_girl running under rails 3.0.5,unexpected tCONSTANT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

This is my Gemfile config:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl', '~>2.0.0.beta1'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails.git', :tag => 'v1.1.beta1'
end
```

This is my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

require "factory_girl"

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/factories/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

I added the `factories` folder to the LOAD_PATH, because I want to keep them in a separate folder.

This is my `factories.rb` file:

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(**FILE**) + '../../spec_helper')

```
Factory.define(:user) do |f|
  f.country("China")
  ... other attributes here
end
```

When I run the tests, using `rake spec:models`, I get this:

```
spec/factories/factories.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
```

I see that this originates from `factory_girl`'s `find_definitions` method. I tried calling this myself, from the spec_helper, but it doesn't change anything. Here's part of the stack trace:

```
** Invoke spec:models (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!

    C:/rails/rcproj/spec/factories/factories.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting
    $end
            f.count...er) do |f|
                                  ^
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `req
    uire'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `req
    uire'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `loa
    d_dependency'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new
    _constants_in'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `loa
    d_dependency'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `req
    uire'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.0.beta2/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:i
    n `find_definitions'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.0.beta2/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:i
    n `each'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.0.beta2/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:i
```

Comment: Comment the first line (require 'spec_helper' ) and try it.

Comment: There is some progress, the test starts running, but at the line saying: `u = Factory(:user).create` it throws a ArgumentError, `Not registered: user`, exception.

Comment: u = Factory(:user) line only create user for you

Comment: I get the same exception if I remove the `.create` from the line.

Comment: Just delete the factory folder and keep your factory file in spec folder and test it. If it is working then your problem is related to loading.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think problem is related to the loading of your factory.
Just write this in your test_helper.rb file

```
   require 'factory_girl'
   Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/factories/*").each do |factory|
     require factory
   end

   OR

   require 'factory_girl'
   FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Comment: Yeah, it was loading related. Moving the factory file in the spec dir solved the problem.

Comment: btw, change Factory.find_definitions to FactoryGirl.find_definitions Factory has been depreceated

Comment: Just did it and I got a message to change Factory.find_definitions to FactoryGirl.find_definitions.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, but it turns out that I simply named my file wrong (factories.rb.rb, thanks to Netbeans). I discovered a few things that would be useful to this page, though.

1. From the [getting started page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md). Factory girl should automatically load the following files if they exist:

   ```
   test/factories.rb
   spec/factories.rb
   test/factories/*.rb
   spec/factories/*.rb
   ```

   Putting the following in test_helper.rb can cause double loading:

   require 'factory_girl'
   Factory.find_definitions

   This caused me to get a `` `add_as': Already defined: <factory name> `` error.
2. The factory_girl_rails gem automatically loads factory_girl.  It's unnecessary, but doesn't appear to have any side effects.
3. I discovered that the FactoryGirl syntax has changed quite a bit since I first learned it in March 2011.  I **highly** recommend everyone check out the getting started page to see some of the changes.