# FactoryGirl: Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, factory-bot

Having a lot trouble getting all the ducks in the right order with FactoryGirl.

Set up a minimalist rails app (3.0.11), factory_girl_rails (1.4.0), factory_girl (2.3.2) & cucumber-rails (1.2.1) and ruby-1.8.7-p352.

**The cucumber test is:**

```
Feature: a
  Scenario: test factory-girl
    Given the following user exists:
    | name    | email               |
    | Brandon | brandon@example.com |
```

**The result is this:**

```
cucumber 
Using the default profile...
"Adam Advertiser"
"a@b.com"
#<User id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email: nil>
Feature: a

  Scenario: test factory-girl        # features/users.feature:2
    Given the following user exists: # factory_girl-2.3.2/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb:100
      | name    | email               |
      | Brandon | brandon@example.com |
      **Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)**
      features/users.feature:3:in `Given the following user exists:'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/users.feature:2 # Scenario: test factory-girl

1 scenario (1 failed)
1 step (1 failed)
0m0.107s
```

*It would seem a load sequence problem, maybe. Would appreciate any help to get this right.
Regards
Ross*

**features/Factories.rb is thus:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        name 'Adam Advertiser'
        email 'a@b.com'
    end
end
pp FactoryGirl.create(:user)

require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'
```

**My features/support/env.rb is:**

```
require 'pp'
require 'cucumber/rails'

require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

**My GemFile is:**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.11'

gem 'sqlite3'


group :development, :test do

    gem 'cucumber-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'     # rails 3 version

end
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Calling `FactoryGirl.find_definitions` right after the `require 'factory_girl_rails'` fixed a similar problem for me.

See [Cannot get factory_girl running under rails 3.0.5,unexpected tCONSTANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298392/cannot-get-factory-girl-running-under-rails-3-0-5-unexpected-tconstant)

Comment: where? test_helper.rb?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to FactoryGirl and I faced a similar error as mentioned in this post.The error I faced was

```
 ArgumentError:
   Not registered: client
```

Factory setup:

/spec/factories.rb

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.email { Faker::Internet.email }
  f.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  f.last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
  f.phone { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
  f.password "foobar"
end
```

/spec/factories/users.rb - Contained child factories for :user

```
Factory.define :client, :parent => :user do |client|
  client.email                    { Factory.next(:client_email) }
  client.password                 "password"
  client.password_confirmation    "password"
end
```

I was running the spec using following command:

```
    app_root$ RAILS_ENV=custom_test bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
```

Thanks to @Ross.The Gem file shown clicked me what was missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem simply add these lines on my spec_helper:

```
require 'factory_girl'
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572059/factory-girl-uninitialized-constant-model-name-with-rails-api), adding `FactoryGirl.find_definitions` will work, but adding `require 'rails_helper'` should eliminate the need for that if you haven't done that.